# Apache Cordova access HTML of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, iframe

Is there a way to get the innerHTML of an iframe in Apache Cordova? Currently I have the following code that is a modification of the onDeviceReady function

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    var iframe = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("http://example.com");
    alert(iframe.document.body.innerHTML);
},
```

This does not alert anything.

I have tried creating an iframe directly in HTML but the src never loads and it always remains blank. I tried installing the whitelist plugin and in config.xml I added

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

but that did not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cordova.InAppBrowser.open` does not return an iframe reference because InappBrowser does not use iframes, it uses a native Webview instance to load and display HTML content.

You will need to use [executeScript()](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#inappbrowserexecutescript) in order to dynamically modify the loaded content of an InappBrowser instance.